# ggplot2: Creating Bar Plot for every element on x-axis but also for the whole sample

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a variable.A in a dataset:

```
variable.A = c('Dem', 'Rep', 'Ind', 'NA')
```

My objective:
I want to plot the means from another variable (variable.X) for 1) 'Dem', 2) 'Rep' and 3) the whole sample (so 'Dem' + 'Rep' + 'Ind').

My first step is to filter out the 'NA' elements in variable.A:

```
new_dataset = dataset %>%
  filter(variable.A != 'NA')
```

Next, I create a bar plot for both variables using the ggplot command:

```
ggplot(new_dataset, aes(x=variable.A, y=variable.X)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = variable.X),
               fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE,
               geom = "bar",
               size = 3)
```

It plots the means for all three group elements.
Here is an image of the plot output:

[image: bar plot]

My questions now are:

1. How can I remove group element 'neutral' from the bar plot?
2. How can I, in addition to plotting the mean for 'Dem' and 'Rep', create a third group in the bar    plot (let's call it 'sample.mean'), that represents the mean to variable.X for the entire sample ('Dem' + 'Rep' + 'Ind')?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this option (not tested as no data was shared). It can be better computing the summary values using `dplyr` with `summarise()`. If you want to add the sample mean you can use `bind_rows()`. The option `limits` in `scale_x_discrete()` allows setting the elements in the axis. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
new_dataset %>%
  group_by(variable.A) %>%
  summarise(variable.X=mean(variable.X)) %>%
  bind_rows(new_dataset %>%
              summarise(variable.X=mean(variable.X)) %>%
              mutate(variable.A='Sample.Mean')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=variable.A, y=variable.X)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c( 'Dem','Rep','Sample.Mean'))
```

**Update:** In order to add the confidence bars, you would need to compute the values for the bands as well as the entire sample in this way. I have used a dummy dataset for that goal:

```
#Keep randomness of simulated data
set.seed(123)
#Data
new_dataset <- data.frame(variable.A=sample(c('Dem','Rep'),50,replace = T),
                          variable.X=round(runif(50,1,10),0))
#Code
new_dataset %>%
  group_by(variable.A) %>%
  summarise(Mean=mean(variable.X),
            SD=sd(variable.X,na.rm=T),
            Low=Mean-qnorm(0.95)*SD,
            Upper=Mean+qnorm(0.95)*SD) %>%
  bind_rows(new_dataset %>%
              summarise(Mean=mean(variable.X),
                        SD=sd(variable.X,na.rm=T),
                        Low=Mean-qnorm(0.95)*SD,
                        Upper=Mean+qnorm(0.95)*SD) %>%
              mutate(variable.A='Sample.Mean')) %>%
  select(-SD) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=variable.A, y=Mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Low,ymax=Upper),width=0.3)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c( 'Dem','Rep','Sample.Mean'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ok, this worked! So if I remove the whole ggplot part in your command, I get a 5 x 2 table:

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  variable.A       variable.X
  <chr>               <dbl>
1 Dem                  3.11
2 Ind                  2.99
3 Rep                  2.58
4 NA                   3.3 
5 Sample Mean          2.94

Can you clarify to me what to do, if I would want to add a confidence interval for each mean in the table AND later also put those confidence intervals on the bar plots?

Comment: @Thomas Hi Thomas, I have updated the solution with the sketch you want. Let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R`

```
df1 <- rbind(aggregate(variable.X ~ variable.A, new_dataset, mean),
       data.frame(variable.A = 'Sample.Mean', variable.X = mean(new_dataset$variable.X))
```

Then, use `ggplot` on the new dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x=variable.A, y=variable.X)) + 
     geom_bar(stat='identity')+
     scale_x_discrete(limits=c('Dem','Rep','Sample.Mean'))
```